How to guess, with spaCy, the frequency of a lemma or a word form in general language use?
I implemented with spaCy a toolkit for Text Analysis, structured in 2 levels:

A. top level implements higher level functions plus interactive web
views in Django;
B. bottom level, linked directly to the spaCy library, provides,
through web API, basic functions extending the spaCy
functionality; it also uses spaCy corpora (DocBin) to persist
reusable results of long-lasting or costly operations, such as the access to open resources on the web.

One extension in B is the annotation of token spans with references to nodes in lexical-semantic networks on the cloud, such as BabelNet (WikiData + WordNet + ...). In order to minimize the calls to the BabelNet web API, I would like to filter out lemmas and word forms very common in the general use of the language.
Question:

Are there, in spaCy, methods to retrieve the frequency of a word type or of a lemma in the training data, considered as representative of texts produced in general language use?
Do the spaCy vocabulary and the associated vectors keep some information related to said frequency?


With all due respect for the moderator, I disagree with her motivation for closing my question. Does it need focusing? I rather thought it was a bit too specific, aimed at a too restricted audience. The points in which it is articulated are closely related, one better explaining the other.
As a result, it got only one reply, but a very good, terse and exhaustive one; of its three points, two directly answer my question and the third one suggests a different kind of solution to my problem.
My conclusion: I got what I was looking for; removing my question would also remove an exemplary answer.

In spaCy, there are indirect methods to retrieve frequency-related information for a word form or lemma based on the data the model was trained on, though spaCy doesn’t provide explicit frequency counts.

SpaCy’s prob attribute in Lexeme gives a log probability based on the training corpus, which can be used as an indicator of general frequency.
Vector norms can act as a rough frequency indicator but are less precise.
For exact frequencies, consider combining spaCy with external frequency resources like wordfreq.

